# SAX Parsing in Android Programming

Tags: android, xml

I want to do SAS Parsing of the Humidity and the Temperature by Lat - Long using a Web Service in my Application. I don't have a clear idea regarding how to do that actually.
So, can anybody please help me with an example if possible.

Thanks,
david

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tutorial [Working with XML on Android](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/#N1014A) has source examples of both SAX and DOM parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use native java xml parser [libraries](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/package-summary.html).