# passing the attribute values from xml file to java file in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

If we pass the Url of the xml file to the .java file,then how to get the  attribute values into the .java file

Comment: Please rephrase your question. As stated, this has no meaning (or too many possible meanings). What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps:
[SAX Parsing in Android Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698166/sax-parsing-in-android-programming)