# How can i parse xml using SAX Parser in Android?

Tags: android, xml, saxparser

Hi i want to parse an XML using SAX parser, like i mentioned below.

Can any one suggest me to write Handler for this?

Thanks in advance

Regards
Shiva.M

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827344/how-to-parse-xml-using-the-sax-parser/4828765#4828765) is perhaps the most detailed answer on XML parsing I have seen lately.
You should check it out.

Answer (score 0):

There are several questions regarding this already. Here are some:

- [SAX Parsing in Android Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698166/sax-parsing-in-android-programming)
- [Parsing XML using sax parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849142/parsing-xml-using-sax-parser)